# element not obeying my css (left/float)

Tags: css

I'm trying to move all the `img` elements of all webpages all the way to the far right beyond the visible screen with the help of userstylesheet.

```
img {
    //display:none !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    left:100% !important;
    //float:right !important;
    //clear:right !important;
}
```

It works most of the time but sometimes it doesn't, [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgdCW.png).

I have even tried all possible combination of settings even the commented out ones. What seems to be the problem?

edit:: I want to be able to still see the images if I scroll just a bit to the left, which is why I was using left:100%.

Comment: Hmmm...Seems like you have a nice desktop!

Comment: Why don't you use display:none or visibility:hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying to find another approach rather than moving the image off the screen, but if you *must* move it off the screen, try:

```
img{
   position:fixed!important;
   top:-99999999px;
   left:-99999999px;
}
```

That should give the image fixed positioning (relative to the window) and move it way off the screen.

Comment: I don't usually care for moving things way off the screen either, but I have, on occasion, done it (ex. for screen-readers only).

Comment: You can target screen readers via other means. A `@media` query should do the trick.

Comment: `@media` looks interesting. I'll have to investigate it more later. At the time, moving the content way off the screen was the only way I could think of to use inline styles (it would have been very difficult to add a style in the main css) to make something one of the first things a screen-reader would read, but yet hidden to normal screens. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: position:fixed works. But, my purpose fails (I want to be able to scroll to the right just a little to view the said images, that's why left:100%). But fixed positioning make the image disappear altogether. I'm sorry if this is whole another issue altogether, but can I achieve this?

Comment: OK, then try removing the `top:-99999999px;` and changing the `left:-99999999px;` to `left:100%;`, but keeping the `position:fixed!important;`. Does that work?

Comment: no i tried it, it does work in the sense that it moves it just off the screen, but horizontal scroll disappears and I can't scroll to it.

Comment: Not knowing your entire situation (where the element is in the html), I don't know exactly what to suggest, but what happens if instead of `position:fixed` and `left:100%`, you do `margin-left:100%;`? That will only work if the element starts all the way at the left though. If you can create a jsfiddle, with an example, people will be better able to help.

Comment: Yeah it would've been smart to recreate that in jsfiddle when posting. I'll try to do just that and post again. Thanks for all the help.